# JavaScript promise chain: I resize an image twice and express response becomes undefined?

Tags: javascript, express, sharp

If I resize an image twice (using the sharp library), my route returns undefined. All my resized images are showing up. It's like somehow, by calling `image.resize` and `.toBuffer()` twice, it's corrupting the res object.

```
router.post('/submit', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  var image = sharp(req.file.buffer)
  image.resize(1500, 1500, { fit: 'inside' }).toBuffer()
    .then(buffer => fs.writeFile('../image-md.jpg', buffer))
    .then(() => image.resize(500, 500, { fit: 'inside' }).toBuffer())
    .then(buffer => fs.writeFile('../image-sm.jpg', buffer))
    .then(() => res.json({ success: true })) 
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ error: err.message }))
})

// res is undefined, and no status is even returned
```

The weird thing is, if I comment out one of the resizes, everything works just fine:

```
router.post('/submit', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  var image = sharp(req.file.buffer)
  image.resize(1500, 1500, { fit: 'inside' }).toBuffer()
    .then(buffer => fs.writeFile('../image-md.jpg', buffer))
    // .then(() => image.resize(500, 500, { fit: 'inside' }).toBuffer())
    // .then(buffer => fs.writeFile('../image-sm.jpg', buffer))
    .then(() => res.json({ success: true })) 
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ error: err.message }))
})

// res.data is { success: true } and status 200 is returned
```

Help!

Comment: Except on the last `.then` of a chain, you should only ever return Promises from a `.then` (otherwise, combine with the next `.then`)

Comment: So should my last ```.then``` be like ```.then(buffer => {  fs.writeFile('../image-sm.jpg', buffer) res.json({ success: true }) })```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is here:

```
.then(() => image.resize(500, 500, { fit: 'inside' }).toBuffer())
```

`.then` should only accept a *function* as a parameter, but you're pass it the result of calling `toBuffer` on calling `image.resize` immediately. Using parentheses to make the grouping easier to understand:

```
.then(
  (() => image.resize(500, 500, { fit: 'inside' }))
    .toBuffer()
)
```

Not 100% sure about the conventions here, but a reader of the code (like me) would *probably* except a reference to `fs` to refer to the built-in `fs` module, whose `writeFile` method doesn't return a Promise, so seeing `.then` or `await` being used on it could be confusing - you might consider it naming it something like `fsPromises`, or something similar (just not `fs`).

It might be easier to read using `async`/`await`:

```
const processImage = async (requestBuffer) => {
  const image = sharp(requestBuffer);
  const bigBuffer = await image.resize(1500, 1500, { fit: 'inside' }).toBuffer();
  await fsPromises.writeFile('../image-md.jpg', bigBuffer);
  const smallBuffer = await image.resize(500, 500, { fit: 'inside' }).toBuffer();
  await fsPromises.writeFile('../image-sm.jpg', smallBuffer);
};

router.post('/submit', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  processImage(req.file.buffer)
    .then(() => {
      res.json({ success: true });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(400).json({ error: err.message })
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm importing the promise version of fs like ```var fs = require('fs').promises```

Comment: Makes sense. Do you know if `image.resize` can handle parallel processing, or can it only work serially? If it can be called in parallel, the speed of the code could be improved with `Promise.all`

Comment: so weird, I tried rewriting using async/await and exactly the same result. The double resize corrupts the successful response. I believe it can handle parallel processing, the library author recommends a promise.all, but I am intentionally not doing that because I actually need to do other things in between resizes.

Comment: Sounds a bit silly, I know, but are you sure you saved the changes? From the original code, I'd *expect* the Promise chain to hang, but if the `.toBuffer` calls are waited for properly (either `await`ed, or returned from the `.then`), there's no reason for anything to hang, unless there's a bug in sharp or `fs`. Using the `await` version, it should be pretty easy to add `console.log`s to see which line isn't progressing, but that seems odd

Comment: I've definitely saved it. :) All I can think is that there is some issue with calling ```.toBuffer()``` twice. If I take the 2nd one out, everything works fine.

Comment: "*but you're pass it the result of calling toBuffer on calling image.resize immediately*" - uh, no. The "*using parenthesis*" snippet is not equivalent at all to the OP's code - it calls `toBuffer` on the arrow function object, which would throw an exception. The original code is totally fine, the `toBuffer` call is inside the arrow function concise body expression, it's equivalent to `.then(() => { return image.resize(500, 500, { fit: 'inside' }).toBuffer(); })`

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be my request timeout. ‍♂️

My timeout was set to 1 second, and when I was doing more than one resize operation, it took longer than 1 second. I upped the timeout to 10 seconds and that fixed it.